# Redirect a caller to another number using twilio client

Tags: twilio

Here is the scenario I need to implement:

a caller calls on twilio number, call redirected to twilio client using voice url.
twilio client accepts call and wants to redirect caller to another number.

when, twilio client redirects caller to another number, client itself connected with another number.

I have used Twilio Rest API calls for Redirect Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing this,

I have used ParentSid of in-progress call.
By using ParentSid, caller can be redirected.

Comment: But how ? , how it is possible in javascript library ?. How to use call via transfer number?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

In order to do this you are going to need to store the CallSid of the initial inbound call.  You can use that CallSid later with the the REST API to [redirect the in-progress](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) call to a new experience.

Once the original inbound call gets redirected the Client should get a disconnect event that you can use to trigger the Client to connect to the next call.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$account_sid = '[AccountSID]'; 
$auth_token = '[AuthToken]'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$call = $client->account->calls->get($callSID); 
$call->update( 
    'Url' => "http://www.url.com/path/to/a/tml/file", 
    'Method' => "GET",  
);
```

http://www.url.com/path/to/a/tml/file Could show a TML/XML file that forward the call, you can add some parameters like ?forwardTo=clientName, and in that TML file create that new call.